# Black screen after ubuntu gnome 16.04 update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, gnome, screen

I have a dual boot windows 10& ubuntu 16.04. I just updated it to 16.04 from 15.10(gnome version) and when the system restared it asked me which system I want to boot,I chose ubuntu and the logo went on and then froze and then just a black screen appeared.I restarted and run the recovery mode,and when I selected repair it said that it coudln't detect my graphic card or something like that.
What to do?

Comment: Add your graphics card model & system specs.